# How to stop auto reindexing in elastic search if any update happens?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am having a big use case with elasticsearch which has millions of records in it.

I will be updating the records frequently, say 1000 records per hour.

I don't want elastic search to reindex for my every update.

I am planning to reindex it on weekly basis.

Any Idea how to stop auto-reindex while update ?

Or any other better suggestion is welcome . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal : Its given in this link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html as "Whenever we do an update, Elasticsearch deletes the old document and then indexes a new document with the update applied to it in one shot." Am i misunderstanding anything  ?

Comment: yes, its correct, but it just reindex 1 document on which you are making an update, not on all the complete index.

Comment: i think what you want to say is "refresh"? The refresh operation is the one that makes the update visible. There's a `refresh_interval` that you can set for indexes.

Comment: read this for more info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html

Comment: @VishnuRanganathan , as archit pointed out if you want to control how frequently you do commit, which is essentially flushing the in-memory index to disk and then only that change is visible on search. then you can do it via  refresh. but you need to tune it.

Comment: @VishnuRanganathan , I don't see any reason why you want to hold your updates for 1 week, also 1k update per hour is really less no of updates , unless you have very small es cluster.

Comment: So if i update one record out of million records, will it reindex the entire million records or it just reindex only that particular updated record ? could you please provide any use case or link for reference  that would be great helpful.

Comment: @VishnuRanganathan , only 1 doc will be updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your informations, It really helped me a lot .

Comment: Sure @AmitKhandelwal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticsearch(ES) update an existing doc in below manner.
  1. Deletes the old doc.
  2. Index a new doc with the changes applied to it.

According to ES docs :-

> In Elasticsearch, this lightweight process of writing and opening a
>   new segment is called a refresh. By default, every shard is refreshed
>   automatically once every second. This is why we say that Elasticsearch
>   has near real-time search: document changes are not visible to search
>   immediately, but will become visible within 1 second.

Note that these changes will not be visible/searchable until ES commits/flush these changes to disk cache and disk,which is control by soft-commit(es refresh interval, which is by default 1 second) and hard-commit(which actually write the document to disk, which prevent it being lost permanently and costly affair than a soft-commit).

You need to make sure, you tune your ES refresh interval, and do proper load testing, as setting it very low and very high has its own pros and cons.

for example setting it very less for example 1 second and if you have too many updates happening than it has a performance hit and it might crash your system. Also setting it very high for example 1 hour means you now don't have a NRT(near real time search) and during that time if your memory could contain again millions of doc(depending on your app) and can cause out of memory error, also committing on such a large memory is a very costly affair.